# JSON.NET how to remove nodes

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have a json like the following:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
        },
        "prop1": "value1",
        "prop2": "value2",
        "__some": "value"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
        },
        "prop3": "value1",
        "prop4": "value2",
        "__some": "value"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I just want to transform this JSON into a different JSON. I want to strip out the "_*metadata" and "*_some" nodes from  the JSON. I'm using JSON.NET.

Comment: I have no experience with C# but I assume you can simply parse the JSON, delete they keys from the resulting data structure and convert it back to JSON again.

Comment: I can do that, but I was looking for JSON.NET way of doing it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I just ended up deserializing to JObject and recursively looping through that to remove unwanted fields. Here's the function for those interested.

```
private void removeFields(JToken token, string[] fields)
{
    JContainer container = token as JContainer;
    if (container == null) return;

    List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
    foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
    {
        JProperty p = el as JProperty;
        if (p != null && fields.Contains(p.Name))
        {
            removeList.Add(el);
        }
        removeFields(el, fields);
    }

    foreach (JToken el in removeList)
    {
        el.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed that. Now I can do a Foreach on my JArray's Children collection to remove all my the properties I want.

Comment: This really helped me - I wanted to log JSON data with sensitive fields replaced by the length of the data.

I was able to get and set p.Value.

Answer (score 25):

Building off of @[Mohamed Nuur]'s answer, I changed it to an extension method which I think works better:

```
 public static JToken RemoveFields(this JToken token, string[] fields)
    {
        JContainer container = token as JContainer;
        if (container == null) return token;

        List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
        foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
        {
            JProperty p = el as JProperty;
            if (p != null && fields.Contains(p.Name))
            {
                removeList.Add(el);
            }
            el.RemoveFields(fields);
        }

        foreach (JToken el in removeList)
        {
            el.Remove();
        }

        return token;
    }
```

Here is unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
     public void can_remove_json_field_removeFields()
     {
        string original = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"__metadata\":{},\"remove\":\"done\",\"prop1\":\"value1\",\"prop2\":\"value2\",\"__some\":\"value\"},{\"__metadata\":{},\"prop3\":\"value1\",\"prop4\":\"value2\",\"__some\":\"value\"}],\"__metadata\":{\"prop3\":\"value1\",\"prop4\":\"value2\"}}}";
        string expected = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"prop1\":\"value1\",\"prop2\":\"value2\",\"__some\":\"value\"},{\"prop3\":\"value1\",\"prop4\":\"value2\",\"__some\":\"value\"}]}}";
        string actual = JToken.Parse(original).RemoveFields(new string[]{"__metadata", "remove"}).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
     }
```

Comment: great solution, tested and used

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new data structure with only the required information and copy the data from the first one. Often that is the simpliest approach. Just an idea.

Comment: But I don't know what the data will be. I want to write a generic function that will take a JSON string and a list of properties to exclude (maybe xpath type?) and returns a new JSON string without the properties that are excluded.

Answer (score -1):

This answer applies if you have a JArray with JTokens, not JObjects:

Here is an example:

```
string json = "[null, null, \"x\", null, null, null, 0,[],[[\"x\"], null,[0],[\"x\"]]]";

    JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

    // Keep first 3 elements, remove the rest
    int max = array.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < max - 3; i++)
    {
        JToken elem = array[3];
        array.Remove(elem);
    }

    json = array.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
```