# Is it possible to remove JSON object from JSON object with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I can merge JSON objects in JSON.NET but;

*I would like to remove JSON object from JSON object like this:*

```
{
"name":"Mike",
"surname":"Dow",
"children":["James","John"],
"data":{"A1":"B1","A2":"B2","A3":"B3"},
"data2":{"A1":"B1","A2":"B2","A3":"B3","A4":"B4"},
"data3":{"A1":{"B1":"C1","B2":"C2"}}
}
```

minus

```
{
"name":"Mike",
"children":["James"],
"data":{"A1":"B1"},
"data2":{"A3":"B3","A4":"B4"},
"data3":{"A1":{"B2":"C2"}}
}
```

equals

```
{
"surname":"Dow",
"children":["John"],
"data":{"A2":"B2","A3":"B3"},
"data2":{"A1":"B1","A2":"B2"},
"data3":{"A1":{"B1":"C1"}}
}
```

Is it possible with JSON.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676159/json-net-how-to-remove-nodes

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I do not want to remove an array of properties but a json. I want the difference of JTokens.

Comment: That s exactly what was done in the other post,,, just need some customization at your end!!!

Comment: How do you want to handle arrays?  Match by index?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you want to handle array matching.  If you simply match array indices, then you can combine [`JToken.SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) with [`JToken.Path`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) to match values in the subtrahend with values in the minuend:

```
        var minuend = JToken.Parse(minuendJson);
        var subtrahend = JToken.Parse(subtrahendJson);
        foreach (var toRemove in subtrahend.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JValue>().Select(t => minuend.SelectToken(t.Path)).Where(t => t != null).ToList())
            toRemove.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
```

Using the extension methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var contained = node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(t => t.Parent is JArray || t.Parent is JObject).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contained != null)
            contained.Remove();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JToken> DescendantsAndSelf(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JToken>();
        var container = node as JContainer;
        if (container != null)
            return container.DescendantsAndSelf();
        else
            return new [] { node };
    }
}
```

If you want to match "leaf" array values by value rather than by index, you could do something like this:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken MatchToken(this JToken target, JToken source)
    {
        var sourceArray = source.Parent as JArray;
        if (sourceArray != null)
        {
            var targetArray = target.SelectToken(sourceArray.Path) as JArray;
            if (targetArray != null)
            {
                // There may be duplicated values in the source and target arrays. If so, get the relative index of the
                // incoming value in the list of duplicates in the source, and return the corresponding value in the list
                // of duplicates in the target.
                var sourceIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, sourceArray.Count).Where(i => JToken.DeepEquals(sourceArray[i], source)).ToList();
                var targetIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, targetArray.Count).Where(i => JToken.DeepEquals(targetArray[i], source)).ToList();
                var matchIndex = sourceIndices.IndexOf(sourceArray.IndexOf(source));
                Debug.Assert(matchIndex >= 0);// Should be found inside its parent.
                if (matchIndex >= 0 && matchIndex < targetIndices.Count)
                    return targetArray[targetIndices[matchIndex]];
                return null;
            }
        }

        return target.SelectToken(source.Path);
    }
}
```

And then

```
        var minuend = JToken.Parse(minuendJson);
        var subtrahend = JToken.Parse(subtrahendJson);
        foreach (var toRemove in subtrahend.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JValue>().Select(t => minuend.MatchToken(t)).Where(t => t != null).ToList())
            toRemove.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
```