# Remove fields from JSON with JSON.NET in F#

Tags: json, f#, json.net

I have a record

```ml
type MyType = {
  Name : string
  Description : string
  OtherField : string
}
```

I'd like to remove some of the fields before I serialize to JSON. How can I do this?

Comment: Personally I will write a new type say `MyType2` with only the required fields, and a function that convert a `MyType` value to a `MyType2` value. With the language like F# it it not frustrated to create a new type.

Comment: In general, yes. I'm doing some fuzz testing where random fields are removed.

Comment: Maybe anonymize types can be used here for serialzation? `{|X = 1|}` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're starting with

```ml
let object = {
  Name = "hi"
  Description = "ho"
  OtherField = "there"
}

#r "nuget:Newtonsoft.Json"
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject object

let fieldsToRemove = [|
  "Name"
  "OtherField"
|]
```

Here's a function that takes an object as input

```ml
let removeFromObject (fields : string []) object =
  let jToken = JToken.FromObject object
  let allFields = jToken.Children() |> Seq.map (fun t -> t :?> JProperty)
  let remainingFields = allFields |> Seq.filter (fun f -> Array.contains f.Name fields |> not)
  let newObject = JObject remainingFields
  let newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObject, Formatting.Indented)
  newJson

removeFromObject fieldsToRemove object
```

And here an adapter for taking a string

```ml
let removeFromString (fields : string []) json =
  let jToken = JObject.Parse json :> JToken
  removeFromObject fields jToken

removeFromString fieldsToRemove json
```

This was inspired by [JSON.NET how to remove nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676159/json-net-how-to-remove-nodes)

Comment: You're not handling the case when the child is not a JProperty. It will crash if it's a JObject.